# For loop in C breaks randomly

Tags: python, arrays, c, for-loop

I've been struggling with this loop in C for a while now. I'm trying to create a string array through a for loop (which I'm not sure I'm doing correctly. I hope I am). Every time I enter a string with a space in it, the for loop breaks and skips all iterations. For example, if I write `S 1` in the command line, it would break.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int players;
    int jerseys;
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &jerseys);
    
    scanf("%d", &players);
    
    char size[jerseys], p[players][100];

    for(jerseys; jerseys > 0; jerseys--){
        
        scanf(" %c", &size[count]); 
        count++;
    }
    getchar();
    count = 0;
    for(players; players>0; players--){
        /*scanf(" %s", p[0] );  */  /*you cant assign arrays in C.*/
        getchar();
        fgets(p[count], 100, stdin);
        printf("%s", p[count]);
        printf("%s", p[count][2]);  /* LINE 29 */
        printf("Hello\n");
        count ++;
    }       


    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, on line 29, if I change the index from 2 to 1, the loop instantly breaks, no matter what I put.

I have a python code for what I essentially want from C:

```
given = []
jerseys = int(input())
if jerseys == 0:
    print(0)
players = int(input())
j = []
requests = 0
for _ in range(jerseys):
    size = input()
    j.append(size)
for _ in range(players):
     p = input().split()
```

I've looked at many places, and I think the problem is with the array, not the new lines, but I have no clue.

Edit:

This is something that would look like what I want to input(and what I usually try):

```
3
3
S
M
L
S 1
S 3
L 2
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `scanf()`.  How do you know a value for `players` was actually read?

Comment: Deltag0ny, With `printf("%s", p[count][2]);`, `"%s"` matches a `char *`.  `p[count][2]` is a `char`.  What do you want  this line of code to do?

Comment: `fgets` *does* consume the newline, in contrast to `scanf` – including `getchar` *inside* the loop thus doesn't appear correct, you might want to call it only once *before*. If you don't want to keep the newline: `char* end = strchr(p[count], '\n'); if(end) { *end = 0; }` (this effort shows that it's a bit unfortunate that `fgets` doesn't return a pointer past the last character read...).

Comment: I personally would prefer loops like `for(int count = 0; count < players; ++count)` – this spares having to increment `count` inside the loop (actually completely one addition), retains the value of `players` for later use and limits the scope of `count` to only where it really is needed.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the input you give to the program.  I note that you destroy the information about how many jerseys there are, and about how many players there are.   You'd do better using more idiomatic `for` loops: `for (int i = 0; i < jerseys; i++) { if (scanf(" %c", &size[i]) != 1) { …error… } }` — which leaves `jerseys` recording how many jerseys were entered.  Similarly for the loop reading the players data.  Remember that `fgets()` includes the newline in the data it returns.

Comment: @Aconcagua: I agree!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, I should absolutely change that to keep jerseys recording what I entered.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I just checked, and a value for players is read.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I want that line to check the number. So if I enter "S 1" . I want it to print out 1.

Comment: @Deltag0ny `printf("%s", p[count][2]);` certainly does not check anything - there is no test.  To print out a single `char` of the string, use `printf("%c", p[count][2]);`  ('c', not 's').  Tip, save time, enable all compiler warnings to avoid foreseeable mistakes like this.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, that was the problem breaking my loop. I want to input things like "S 1", but I'm confused about why 1 is actually an int. If I assign it to an array of strings, wouldn't "S 1" be entirely a string?

Comment: Nevermind, it was that I put %s instead of %c. Now I feel stupid.

Answer (score 1):

> If the input characters do not match the control characters or are of the wrong type for a formatted input scanf terminates leaving the offending character as the next character to be read.

If you write *1`* in the command line,  then `jerseys` set to `1`, but `players` is a random int because the *`* not match the *%d* format. So in you program, your `players` variable may be a big int.

So when you use `scanf`, you'd better to check the return value like

```
if ((scanf("%d", &players) != 1) {
    /* error handle */
}
```

I run the code and `segmentation fault` is raise.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code does not cleanly compile!

Here is the output from the `gcc` compiler:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o"

untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:17:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   17 |     for(jerseys; jerseys > 0; jerseys--){
      |     ^~~
      
untitled.c:24:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   24 |     for(players; players>0; players--){
      |     ^~~
      
untitled.c:29:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   29 |         printf("%s", p[count][2]);  /* LINE 29 */
      |                 ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |           |
      |                  char *      int
      |                 %d
      
untitled.c:10:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
   10 |     int i;
      |         ^
      
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Please correct the code AND check the returned status from the C library I/O functions

Regarding:

```
Compilation finished successfully.
```

since the compiler output several warnings,  This statement only means the compiler made some (not necessarily correct) guesses as to what you meant.